# A function to test if all svg objects are visible

Tags: javascript, svg

Im making a simple memory game within svg and javascript. The basic outline of the game is to match the correct shapes. There is a total of 20 rect. I am now trying to create a function that checks when all the rects opacity are 0, create an alert box and stop my timer. Im wondering how to do this, this is my code so far. Thanks in advance.

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 var shape1;
 var shape2;
 var prevTile;
 var click = 0;

 function changerect(evt, shape) { // this reduces the opacity to o of the tiles

    var svgobj=evt.target; // Reduced of pressed Rect
    svgobj.style.opacity= 0;


    click++;  // Increment Click counter        
              // If click == 1 we should take note of shape
              // If click == 2 we should take note of shape and compare to previous shape

    if(click == 1) {
        // We're taking note of what has been pressed
        // Taking note of shape and tile
        shape1 = shape;
        prevTile = svgobj;
    }

    else if (click == 2) {
        shape2 = shape;   // Check to see if there is a match
        if(shape1 == shape2);// YES there is a match

              // NO there is no match
        else {
        // Hide 2 shapes after some time
            setTimeout(hideTiles, 2000);
               function hideTiles() {
                 svgobj.style.opacity = 1;
                     prevTile.style.opacity = 1;
            } } }

    if(click == 2) {// Reset click to 0 after 2 clicks
        click = 0;
    }
  }
  function rectClicked(shape) {     
  }

   </script>
```

This is the  body of the HTML.

```
  <body onload="startstop();"> 

  <input id="clock" type="text" value="00:00" style="text-align:     center;background-color:white;border:1px solid gray;font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;" readonly><br>

<input id="startstoptimer" TYPE=HIDDEN><br>


 <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='700'   width='700'>


 <defs><!--GRADIENT  ON TILES/STYLING-->
     <linearGradient id="gradient">
         <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #ffefdb"></stop>
         <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #8b8878"></stop>
     </linearGradient>
</defs>


 <!--BACKGRROUND-->
<rect x="20" y="2" rx="20" ry="20" width="600" height="480"     style="fill:rgb(197, 213, 209)"/>

<!--TILE ONE-->

<!--my svg shape  underneath-->
<rect id="rectB" x="245" y="125" width="50" height="50" style="fill:green;stroke:orange;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1.0;stroke- opacity:1.0"/>

 <!--below is the rect that covers svg shape-->
 <rect id="recB" onclick='changerect(evt,"rectB")' x="220" y="100" rx="20" ry="20" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)">

<!-- initial animation-->
<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur="5s" repeatCount="definite"/>
```

```
<!--my svg shape  underneath-->
<circle id="circleC" cx="270" cy="260" r="20" fill="purple"/> 

<!--below is the rect that covers svg shape-->
<rect id="cirC" onclick='changerect(evt,"circleC")' x="220" y="210" rx="20" ry="20" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)">

<!-- initial animation-->
<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur="5s" repeatCount="definite"/></rect>


<!--TILE THREE-->

<circle id="circleC" cx="380" cy="150" r="20" fill="purple"/> 

<rect id="cirC" onclick='changerect(evt,"circleC")' x="330" y="100" rx="20" ry="20" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)">

<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur="5s" repeatCount="definite"/> </rect>  

<!--TILE FOUR-->

<rect id="rectC" x="355" y="235" width="50" height="50" style="fill:green;stroke:orange;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1.0;stroke-opacity:1.0"/>

<rect id="recB" onclick='changerect(evt,"rectB")' x="330" y="210" rx="20" ry="20" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)">

<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur="5s" repeatCount="definite"/></rect>               

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Im just a beginner here and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the images are in some kind of Container like this:

```
<div id="testContainer">
 <img src="">
 <img src="">
 <img src="">
 <img src="">
</div>
```

so you could iterate through the children of this container:

```
var counter = 0
var children = document.getElementById("testContainer").children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   if(children[i].style.opacity === 0)
   {
      counter++;
   }
}
if(counter === 20){
   console.log('finished!');
   window.alert('finished!');
   // stop timer
}
else{
   counter = 0;
}
```

There are much more sophisticated ways to do this but this could be a simple approach in order to solve this particular problem.

**Edit:**
Ok, the shapes are inside the svg- image. If you want to keep your structure I assume to assign a class attribute to all of your rectangle shapes like this:

```
<rect class="shapeToFlip" x="20" y="2" rx="20" ry="20" width="600" height="480"     style="fill:rgb(197, 213, 209)"/>
```

In order to get all shapes you could use the getElementsByClassName function which returns an array:

```
var allShapes = document.getElementsByClassName("shapeToFlip");
```

after that you can iterate through the array like I mentioned earlier.

Comment: My images underneath are SVG shapes too.                                                       My code is                                                                                           <circle id="circleC" cx="270" cy="260" r="20" fill="purple"/>                     //my svg shape which sits underneath my tiles.                                              So how could i put these SVG shapes into a div container? Thanks @Linu for your help. Im super new to this.

Comment: Would you please provide the HTML structure of your project so that we can imagine the outline a little bit better?